# Guardar imagen en blob o por ruta?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Que seria lo mas adecuado y una buena práctica para guardar imagenes en base de datos

Por ruta o dentro del gestor como dato

Comment: La pregunta "lo más adecuado" es subjetivo y por ello basado en opiniones , lo que es un motivo de cierre. Has de objetivizar la pregunta. Mira [ask] para mejorarla. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Lo que actualmente se hace es guardar la ruta del archivo subido y se sube el archivo ni siquiera al servidor sino a un servicio en la nube mas especializado como [Amazon Web Store o simplemente AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/es/s3/) ventajas de eso, tu servidor no tiene que servir esos archivo estáticos que subes por lo que se libera la carga ademas esos CDN están especializados en servir archivos estáticos tienen varias replicas a lo largo del mundo por lo que por lo general tendrá tiempos de carga menor que si lo subieses a tu propio servidor.

El siguiente fragmento fue extraido de [Phpcentral - Ventajas y desventajas de guardar imagenes en la base de datos](http://www.phpcentral.com/pregunta/252/ventajas-y-desventajas-de-guardar-imagenes-en-la-base-de-datos)

Los Problemas de almacenar en BD son:

- Tiempo de acceso a los archivos: siempre es más rápido el acceso a filesystem que a una base de datos (la db requiere conexión, autenticación, autorización, etc).
- Incremento en tamaño de la base de datos: si debemos persistir una gran cantida de archivos y/o pocos pero de gran tamaño, esto hará que nuestra base de datos se incremente en tamaño, y en consecuencia su administración será más complicada (backups y restores mas lentos, tiempos de bloqueo de la base de dato mayores).
- Acceso diferido a los archivos: al persistir los archivos en una base de datos, para accederlos siempre se requerirá de un cliente de base de datos que lea el contenido y luego nos lo presente en forma de archivo. En el caso de filesystem podremos acceder directamente a los archivos físicos.
- Mayor complejidad: la persistencia en base de datos requiere un mayor conocimiento técnico y más código/procesos/validaciones que en el caso del filesystem.
- Aumento de los requerimientos de infraestructura: se requiere de mayor memoria RAM, procesador, espacio en disco, etc., requerimientos especificados por el DBMS a ser utilizado en la persistencia de archivos (en la práctica, por lo general ya estamos usando un DBMS para nuestro sistema, por lo que el incremento en infraestructura no suele ser considerable, distinto sería si tuvieramos que considerar implementar persistencia en base de datos en un sistema que no utiliza una base de datos).

En general casi siempre se optara por usar el filesystem para almacenarlos pero hay diferentes escenarios donde es mas practico almacenar en base de datos.